# How to create custom column with auto-increment characters

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want to show one custom column as alias but need to increment by using auto character.

```
id      subid   dollar  packetname
168     355     5813    ND-1
169     355     359     ND-1
170     356     559     ND-2
171     362     4536    ND-10
172     362     484     ND-10
134     329     4698    ND-12
135     329     435     ND-12
125     330     6293    ND-13
126     330     4293    ND-13
127     330     693     ND-13
```

I need a output with another **updated packet.** column with autoincrement character

```
id      subid   dollar  packetname      updated packet
168     355     5813    ND-1            ND-1
169     355     359     ND-1            ND-1A
170     356     559     ND-2            ND-2
171     362     4536    ND-10           ND-10
172     362     484     ND-10           ND-10A
134     329     4698    ND-12           ND-12
135     329     435     ND-12           ND-12A
125     330     6293    ND-13           ND-13
126     330     4293    ND-13           ND-13A
127     330     693     ND-13           ND-13B
```

Comment: Hmm, suppose 37th column will be `ND-13Z`, what would you expect 38th to be?

Comment: @Timekiller no I am not expect anything on 38th. My max requirement is A to G only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such query to make additional field

```
SELECT concat(packetname, 
              elt(if(@t=packetname, @n:=@n+1, @n:=1),
                  '','A','B','C','D','E','F','G')) `updated packet`, 
       id, subid, dollar, @t:=packetname packetname
    FROM t
      cross join
         (SELECT @n:=1, @t:="") n
  order by packetname
```

[demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ed3cb/1)

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to `SELECT` out the current packet table, modifying it along the way, and `INSERT` it into a new table.  Once you have completed this operation, you can drop the original table, and then rename the new one to the old one.

```
INSERT INTO newpacket (id, subid, dollar, packetname, `updated packet`)
SELECT p1.id, p1.subid, p1.dollar, p1.packetname, p2.`updated packet`
FROM packet p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT p.id, p.subid,
        CASE WHEN (SELECT p.id - MIN(t.id) FROM packet t WHERE t.subid = p.subid) > 0
        THEN CONCAT(packetname,
                    CHAR(((SELECT p.id - MIN(t.id) FROM packet t WHERE t.subid = p.subid) + 64) USING utf8))
        ELSE packetname END AS `updated packet`
    FROM packet p
) p2
ON p1.subid = p2.subid AND p1.id = p2.id
```

Comment: Is it safe to operate on `id`/`subid` though? What if `id` values are sparse in real data? What if there are same `packetname` for different `subid`?

Comment: I'm assuming that `id` - `subid` combinations are unique.  I think we need to make some assumptions to even guess a solution here.  By the way, @Timekiller is an appropriate name.  I have already spent one hour on this problem.

Comment: Well what error do you get?  SQLFiddle has been down for a while now.

Comment: I was missing a condition in the `ON` clause.  Could you please try one more time?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger.

```
create trigger my_trigger before insert on mytable for each row 
begin
DECLARE samecount INT;
  set samecount = ( select count(*) from mytable where packetname = new.packetname );
  if samecount = 0 then
    set new.updated_packet = new.packetname;
  else
    set new.updated_packet = concat(new.packetname,conv(samecount+9,10,36));
  end if;
end;
```

Before a new row is inserted, it counts how many rows with same `packetname` exist. When there is one or more, the count+9 is converted to base 36 - it's almost the same as HEX except all the way up to Z. So, if count is 1, it becomes `1+9=10=A`. The resulting value is concatenated with `packetname`.
If same rows exceed 37, it will not fail, but will append `10` for 38 instead.

Keep in mind that this isn't exactly `auto increment` and it could be subject to race conditions, when two users insert the same `packetname` in exactly the same time, the count query can return the same value for both.

**EDIT:** 
Note that this solution for when you'll need to insert *new* rows into that table afterwards and want them to have `updated_packet` filled automatically. If you want to also update existing rows, one way is to create a new table with same structure, create that trigger on a new table and then do

```
insert into newtable(id, subid, dollar, packetname)
select id, subid, dollar, packetname from oldtable
```