# Condition checking while using sum() in mysql

Tags: mysql

AM NEW TO MYSQL... HELP ME TO SORT OUT THIS...

I have a result like

```
 NO,     TYPE,  FEE_AMT
'2156', 'FTP2', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP4', 200.00
'2156', 'FTP5', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP6', 100.00
'2156', 'FTP3', 100.00
```

I want to sum all FEE_AMT, in which if the type=`'FTP5'` I want to square the respective FEE_AMT and then add... I have tried sum(fee_amt) only...

**EXPECTED OUTPUT IS: 10,500...**

---

**edit**

100+200+(100*100)+100+100

I WANT TO SQUARE THE FEE AMOUNT IF FEE TYPE='FTP5'

THANKS IN ADVANCE... :)

Comment: Can you show us a reproducible sample and output?  I don't see how you're getting `10,500` from your question.  Do you want the sum of the squares, or the square of the sum?

Comment: Mr Tim... Please see my edited question... Thanks for your response first of all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN TYPE='FTP5' THEN FEE_AMT*FEE_AMT ELSE FEE_AMT END) AS FeeSum
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329910/how-to-create-custom-column-with-auto-increment-characters/34330573#34330573) if you want to see a really ugly query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(
    if(TYPE='FTP5',FEE_AMT*FEE_AMT,FEE_AMT)) AS FeeSum
FROM yourTable